# IF statements excel help referring to multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-statements, if

I am struggling a bit with my `IF` statement and was wondering if I can get some help. I made a new column and want to have it filled based on three other cells. For example, you can see the attachment below. I want the new column to say, for example, `F2` should just return Male, `F3` should return Male 18+. `F4` should return Male 18+ College Degree, and `F5` should return 18+ College Degree.

Sample data

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Use multiple `IF` Statements each separated by `&" "&` (concatenation of a blank space between each IF).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to stick to a regular `IF` function, you can simply combine the various conditions. In particular, instead of `value_if_false`, insert the next `IF` statement. Both approaches assume that your data is in the range `A1:C5`, and you paste the formula into cell `D2` and copy it down. The values are divided by ";", but you can simply delete this if you do not need it.

IF Function:

```
=IF(AND(A2:C2)=TRUE,"Male; 18+; College Degree",
IF(AND(A2,B2)=TRUE,"Male; 18+",
IF(AND(A2,C2)=TRUE,"Male; College Degree",
IF(AND(B2,C2)=TRUE,"18+; College Degree",
IF(A2=TRUE,"Male",IF(B2=TRUE,"18+",IF(C2=TRUE,"College Degree","ERROR")))))))
```

---

Since this procedure is quite tedious, especially if you have multiple conditions, another approach would be to simply use the `FILTER` function for the cases that are TRUE and then join them accordingly.

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,FILTER($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2=TRUE))
```

Comment: Nice use of TEXTJOIN and FILTER, but I don't like that big nested IF!

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=CONCAT(FILTER($A$1:$C$1,A2:C2=TRUE)&" ","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have a recent enough version of Excel to use dynamic arrays, just a concatenated series of IFs would do the job, but not great to scale to many columns.

You will need to add spaces, and then use TRIM to get rid of any "unused" ones at the ends or a double in the middle (for "Male__College degree"):

```
=TRIM(IF($A2,$A$1,"") &" "& IF($B2,$B$1,"") &" "& IF($C2,$C$1,""))
```

This relies on the fact that $A2 = TRUE is the same as just $A2. Since $A2 is already true or false, you don't need to test if TRUE=TRUE (like 1=1).

If you don't actually have True and False already, but something else such as Yes/No, you need to extend each IF as a more formal condition:

```
=...IF($A2="Yes",$A$1,"")...
```